How to make the text after the table stay within the same paragraph
Text A
Table
Text B
All the three stay in the same paraph. The last line of Text A leaves some space, which, if nothing is done, will be filled by the beginning words of Text B. How can I let Text B starts after the table and within the same paragraph?
I have tried put [H] besides \begin{table}. It will make Text B starts after the table, but in a new paragraph.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
